# Regex to exclude word from matches java code

Tags: java, regex

Maybe someone could help me. I'm trying to include within a java code a regex to match all strings except the ZZ78. I'd like to know what it's missing in the regex I have.

The input string is str = "**ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78**"

and I'm trying with this regex **(?:(?![ZZF8]).)*** but if you test in http://regexpal.com/
this regex against the string, you'll see that is not working completely.

```
str = new String ("ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(?![ZZ78]).)*");
```

the matched strings should be

```
ab57cd
efghZZ7ij@klm
noCODpqr
stuvw27z@xyz
```

**Update:**

Hello Avinash Raj and Chthonic Project. Thanks so much for your help and solutions provided.

I originally thougth in split method, but I was trying to avoid get empty strings as result
when for example the delimiter string is at the beginning or at the end of the main string.

Then, I thought that a regex could help me to extract all except "ZZ78", avoiding in this way
empty results in the output.

Below I show the code using split method (Chthonic´s) and regex (Avinash´s) both produce empty
string if the commented "if()" conditions are not used.

Does the use of those "if()" are the only way to not print empty strings? or could be the regex 
tweaked a little bit to match not empty strings?

This is the code I have tested so far:

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RegexTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("########### Matches with Split ###########");
            String str = "ZZ78ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
            for (String s : str.split("ZZ78")) {
                //if ( !s.isEmpty() ) {
                    System.out.println("This is a match <<" + s  + ">>");
                //} 
            }
            System.out.println("##########################################");

            System.out.println("########### Matches with Regex ###########");
            String s = "ZZ78ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:(?!ZZ78).)*)(ZZ78|$)");
            Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
            while(matcher.find()){
                //if ( !matcher.group(1).isEmpty() ) { 
                    System.out.println("This is a match <<" + matcher.group(1) + ">>");
                //}    
            }
        }
    }

**and the output (without use the "if()´s"):**
########### Matches with Split ###########
This is a match <<>>
This is a match <<ab57cd>>
This is a match <<efghZZ7ij@klm>>
This is a match <<noCODpqr>>
This is a match <<stuvw27z@xyz>>
##########################################
########### Matches with Regex ###########
This is a match <<>>
This is a match <<ab57cd>>
This is a match <<efghZZ7ij@klm>>
This is a match <<noCODpqr>>
This is a match <<stuvw27z@xyz>>
This is a match <<>>
```

Thanks for help so far.

Thanks in advance

**Update #2:**

Excellent both of your answers and solutions. Now it works very nice. This is the final code I've tested with both solutions.

Many thanks again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("########### Matches with Split ###########");
        String str = "ZZ78ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
        Arrays.stream(str.split("ZZ78")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("##########################################");

        System.out.println("########### Matches with Regex ###########");
        String s = "ZZ78ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:(?!ZZ78).)*)(ZZ78|$)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
        ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(matcher.find()){
            allMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        for (String s1 : allMatches)
            if (!s1.equals(""))
                list.add(s1);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

And output:
########### Matches with Split ###########
ab57cd
efghZZ7ij@klm
noCODpqr
stuvw27z@xyz
##########################################
########### Matches with Regex ###########
[ab57cd, efghZZ7ij@klm, noCODpqr, stuvw27z@xyz]
```

Comment: Why do you want to use pattern for this? Why not use `String#split()`?

Comment: yep, just split on `ZZ78`. I think it would be `string.split("ZZ78")`

Comment: `[ZZ78]` matches a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must need to remove the character class since `[ZZ78]` matches a single charcater from the given list. `(?:(?!ZZ78).)*` alone won't give the match you want. Consider this `ab57cdZZ78` as an input string. At first this `(?:(?!ZZ78).)*` matches the string `ab57cd`, next it tries to match the following `Z` and check the condition `(?!ZZ78)` which means match any character but not of `ZZ78`. So it failes to match the following `Z`, next the regex engine moves on to the next character `Z`   and checks this `(?!ZZ78)` condition. Because of the second `Z` isn't followed by `Z78`, this `Z` got matched by the regex engine.

```
String s = "ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:(?!ZZ78).)*)(ZZ78|$)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
ab57cd
efghZZ7ij@klm
noCODpqr
stuvw27z@xyz
```

**Explanation:**

- `((?:(?!ZZ78).)*)` Capture any character but not of `ZZ78` zero or more times.
- `(ZZ78|$)` And also capture the following `ZZ78` or the end of the line anchor into group 2.
- Group index 1 contains single or group of characters other than `ZZ78`

**Update:**

```
String s = "ZZ78ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((?:(?!ZZ78).)*)(ZZ78|$)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(matcher.find()){
    allMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
}
for (String s1 : allMatches)
    if (!s1.equals(""))
        list.add(s1);

System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[ab57cd, efghZZ7ij@klm, noCODpqr, stuvw27z@xyz]
```

Comment: Hello Avinash, thanks for your help. I get empty strings if ZZ78 is at the beggining or end. Please may you check my original post below the "Update" part. I've added the code I've tested. Regards

Comment: Hello Avinash, Excellent your new code, it works perfect too and is stored as array that coudl help me in different ways too. Many thanks for thee help and time both of you guys. Regards

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ab57cdZZ78efghZZ7ij@klmZZ78noCODpqrZZ78stuvw27z@xyzZZ78";
    for (String s : str.split("ZZ78"))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
ab57cd
efghZZ7ij@klm
noCODpqr
stuvw27z@xyz
```

If the pattern used to split the string is at the beginning (i.e. "ZZ78" in your example code), the first element returned will be an empty string, as you have already noted. To avoid that, all you need to do is filter the array. This is essentially the same as putting an `if`, but you can avoid the extra condition line this way. I would do this as follows (in Java 8):

```
String test_str = ...; // whatever string you want to test it with
Arrays.stream(str.split("ZZ78")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).foreach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hello Chthonic, thanks for your help. I get empty strings if ZZ78 is at the beggining or end. Please may you check my original post below the "Update" part. Is there a way to avoid this with split method or only using the "if()" I have commented in the code?. Regards

Comment: You can't avoid the empty string without adding a condition in some form. The simplest way is to have an `if` condition, as you did. I added another way to the answer.

Comment: Excellent Chthonic. I got the point. It works very well!!. Regards